# iTunes has reset my phone instead even though I chose update - is all data lost?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, restore

This is a nightmare, I have an iphone 11 pro, the storage was almost full (256gb), apps did not open, so I restarted it. it then got stuck on apple logo. hard reset did not help, so I followed Apple guide, connected it to tunes to restore mode.

It said explicitly that if I choose "update" data will not be harmed. I did it and it prompted me to download iOS 15.x.
It downloaded 7GB of the new iOS, saying "itunes is downloading a software update and will install it", but then it proceeded straight into saying "itunes is preparing to restore the software on this phone".

I didn't have any choice, and I thought maybe it just means restoring the software and not the phone. But when it finised after 15 min, all the iPhone was reset! 3U tools showed capacity of 8GB, and the last backup I have is 2.5 years old!

I trusted Apple guidance and it scr*wed me over! What am I supposed to do right now?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135021/discussion-on-question-by-stackaloo-itunes-has-reset-my-phone-instead-even-thoug).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are in a tough spot if you didn’t follow step one of the update to iOS 15 guide concerning making a backup.

- https://support.apple.com/ios/update

The options when a backup fails or is discovered to be older than expected are:

- Paying for professional data recovery is the best option but it takes time to research and get an estimate. Then you have to weigh your budget for recovering from the lapse in backups.
- DIY data recovery isn’t something I would recommend if you’re not in the habit of already performing restores from older than the most recent automatic backup or doing updates on iOS that aren’t the latest.

My personal advice is don’t further beat yourself up for missing the options to backup before or place extra responsibility on Apple for managing your data. This is how we all learn, by losing data or helping someone we know who lost data.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

The upgrade process doesn’t set out to delete data and has many checks in place to make sure there’s enough room to always preserve contents, but not all processes, instructions or warnings work all the time for everyone. Once you’ve had time to digest and research other posts here on data recovery you can decide if you  need to restore the device and trust backups and test or need to call in help of some sort.

- [How can I recover iPhone data lost after iOS upgrade?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/31662/)
- [Upgrading my 3GS to iOS 5.1.1, I lost all my apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53230/)
- [Restore iPhone 3GS without backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/76348/)